# How to push data to the end of the array filled with sqlitedata

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

I have this method:

```
  Future<Task> save(Task task) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    task.id = await dbClient.insert(TABLE, task.toMap());
    return task;
  }
```

Here I know how to save data to DB, but it stores it like [1,2,3]
How can I save data like this [1,2,3,] -> insertStart(data) -> [data, 1,2,3]
I want to save data to the beginning of the array
I tried to do this:

```
Task e = Task(here goes negative value -1, -2 but I did not achieve it, task.name,
task.title, task.subtasks);
dbHelper.save(e);
```

Comment: honestly, i have no idea what your problem is... what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @pskink I showed how I save data to the DB, it stores elements in an array in order, I need to store it to the beginning of an array, not to the end

Comment: you cannot change the way the new data is inserted, instead so you have to use "ORDER BY" clause in your "SELECT" statement